# Как показать текущее время и дату?

Tags: java, android

Как показать в `TextView` текущее время и дату?

Answer (score 8):

По старому:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    textview.setText(format.format(new Date()));
```

По новому:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    textview.setText(LocalDate.now().format(formatter));
```

Comment: в версии android studio 3.3.3 прекрасно сработал вариант "По старому"